# Finding all continuous $f$ on $\mathbb R$ such that for each $r\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q $ , $f(rx)/f(x)$ is constant $\forall x\ne 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, continuity

Can we determine all continuous functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that for every $r \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ , $\exists k_r \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(rx)=k_rf(x) , \forall x \in \mathbb R$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting $x=1$ we have $k_r = \frac{f(r)}{f(1)} $ thus $$f(rx) =\frac{f(r)}{f(1)} f(x) $$ for all $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} , x\in\mathbb{R} .$ Now let $v\in\mathbb{Q} $ and let $v_n\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} ,$ $v_n \to v$ then by the continuity of $f$ we obtain $$f(vx)\leftarrow f(v_nx) =\frac{f(v_n)}{f(1)} f(x) \to\frac{f(v)}{f(1)} f(x) $$ for all $v\in \mathbb{Q} , x\in\mathbb{R} .$ Therefore $$f(rx) =\frac{f(r)}{f(1)} f(x) $$ for all $r\in\mathbb{R} , x\in\mathbb{R} .$ Substituting $r=e^u , v=e^s  $ we obtain $$f(e^{u+s} ) =\frac{1}{f(1) } f(e^u ) f(e^s ) $$ hence $$\ln f(e^{u+s} ) =-\ln f(1) +\ln f(e^u ) +\ln f(e^u )$$ so $$\ln f(e^x ) =\ln f(1) +cx$$ thus $$f(e^x ) =f(1) e^{cx} $$ and therefore $$f(x) =\begin{cases} f(1) x^c \mbox{ if } x>0\\ f(-1) |x|^c \mbox{ if } x\leqslant 0\end{cases} .$$

Comment: Not quite.  For example, $f(x) = x$ satisfies the equation but is not of that form.

Comment: Yes you're right ,I have just edited.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can.

First steps:
Since $f(r) = k_r f(1)$, your equation implies $f(rx) f(1) =f(r) f(x)$ for all $x$ and all irrational $r$.  By continuity, $f(xy) f(1) = f(x) f(y)$ for all $x,y$.  Note that if $f(1) = 0$ then $f\equiv 0$.  Otherwise, take $g(x) = f(x)/f(1)$.  Then $g$ satisfies $g(xy) = g(x) g(y)$ and is again continuous, with $g(1) = 1$.  We also have $g(-1) = \pm 1$.

Next show that $g(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$, and that
$h(t) = \ln (g(e^t))$ satisfies [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).